# Always start ipython with pylab being equal to inline, but toggle it off at some time

Tags: python, configuration, alias, ipython

Is there any convention or configuration setting for how to start `IPython` shell? For example, when I start IPython, I almost always start it with `pylab --inline`. One approach is to create an alias, such as `alias ipython="ipython --pylab inline"`. However, I think it's impossible to start the shell with different options (other than `inline` option) once I decide to create and use the alias.

So is it feasible to always start the shell with `pylab=inline` option, but still to toggle it off whenever I don't need it (or more correctly, whenever I want to avoid it)?

(Don't suggest to create an alias with different names, such as `ipy` or `ipyWithPylab`, please.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ipython qtconsole --help-all` says :

```
--IPKernelApp.matplotlib=<CaselessStrEnum>
    Default: None
    Choices: ['auto', 'gtk', 'inline', 'osx', 'qt', 'qt4', 'tk', 'wx']

--IPKernelApp.pylab=<CaselessStrEnum>
    Default: None
    Choices: ['auto', 'gtk', 'inline', 'osx', 'qt', 'qt4', 'tk', 'wx']
    Pre-load matplotlib and numpy for interactive use, selecting a particular
    matplotlib backend and loop integration.
```

so `c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib='inline'`in your `*_config.py`(probably in `~/.ipython/profile_default`) will work. Please read [how to configure IPyton](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/ipython.html), usually doc explain a lot of things on how to do stuff.

Be careful though, there is a difference between having inlines figures and having a `%pylab` kernel. It is not possible to un-pylab a kernel (like it is impossible in python to un-import a module). With 1.0 and above and **recent** matplotlib, you can toggle inline/not inline with the `%matplotlib <backend>` magic.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I did try it, but it didn't work. And I just found that I don't have QT4 installed in my OS X system (which I had before, not sure when it's gone). However, starting the shell with `ipython --pylab inline` works, despite it spitting out an warning, while starting it with configuration file setting doesn't... I don't know the reason, but I think it's the best, at least right now, to bother to starting it with `--pylab inline` option. Thanks a lot for your answer, though.