# ipython notebook on linux VM running matplotlib interactive with nbagg

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, vagrant, jupyter-notebook

I want buttons and other interactive matplotlib objects to appear from within my ipython notebook. [image: screenshot]

Here is what I've done:

1. Installed http://datasciencetoolbox.org, it is a vagrant box with ipython installed and version 1.3.1 of matplotlib.
2. I needed to upgrade matplotlib to the latest version, because it has this capability to do inline interactive plots.  [What's new in Matplotlib 1.4.1](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#the-nbagg-backend)
   I needed to run `sudo apt-get install pkg-config` and
   `sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade`in order to get that going.
3. Then, in order to produce the nice (i.e. error-free) screenshot below, I went into the `.ipython/dst-profile/ipython_notebook_config.py` file and erased the line about `IPKernelApp.pylab='inline'` to be able to run the `matplotlib.use('nbagg')` command.
4. Then I was able to create the screenshot below. However, things still look poor. Those buttons are not buttons.  That is an image of buttons. Please advise on how to make those buttons come to life!

Oh... and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902984/always-start-ipython-with-pylab-being-equal-to-inline-but-toggle-it-off-at-some) out if this helps you help me.

Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Also, if you are only targeting the note book for interactive plots, you might do far better using `@interact` which is some black-magic that makes you a javascript widget that will do your interaction.

Comment: @tcaswell, how exactly would i go about using @interact?

Comment: Look up the documentation, I have never actually used it just seen demos

Comment: Maybe I won't need to for now. I will keep it in mind though.  Thanks. And upgrading was great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you are facing two issues

- the `%pylab inline`call overrides the `matplotlib.use('nbagg')`call, to use the *inline* backend instead of the *nbagg* backend which you are actually wanting. If you use a recent version of IPython (2.3) you can directly use `%matplotlib nbagg` (or `%matplotlib notebook`) to load the nbagg backend instead of your `%pylab`call.
- once you enabled the *nbagg* backend you will need to explicitly show it, ie. add a `plt.show()` call at the end of your script -> **Update**: with IPython 2.3.1 this is no longer needed (thanks @tcaswell for the hint)

With this you get the interactive matplotlib experience embedded in the IPython notebook. However, a quick try of your code does't yield to the desired result. The Button reacts and the callback is executed but the `print` call doesn't show anything. Anyway, to see that it's working try the following simple example (requires IPython 2.3):

```py
%matplotlib nbagg
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def callback(event):
    plt.text(event.xdata, event.ydata, 'clicked')

f,a = plt.subplots(1)
b1 = Button(a,'Button1')
b1.on_clicked(callback)
plt.show()
```

Btw. it is highly recommended to use %matplotlib instead of %pylab as later leads to some side effects, see [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Carreau/posts/blob/master/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb).

Comment: The explicit need to call show should be fixed by some combination of upgrading mpl/ipython, but I am not sure how far (see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6587 ) . +1 on not using pylab, we can't _actually_ remove it from the source, but are working on expunging it from the docs (both mpl + IPython)

Comment: I've upgraded ipython since this original post: https://www.dropbox.com/s/co17ndyts0v8a4q/Screenshot%202014-11-13%2013.04.15.png?dl=0, then i edited my notebook config file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ox1i4k5vl355e06/Screenshot%202014-11-13%2013.14.30.png?dl=0

finally, i started a new notebook, and ran your code without the first line and the last (so no `plt.show()`): https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyy0wosbkupnbtg/Screenshot%202014-11-13%2013.18.14.png?dl=0

Comment: So that settles tcaswell's plt.show thing, and it handles my problem which I've spent over 5 hours tinkering with. Now I can finally use ipython notebook with interactive plots! Yay. Thanks @Jakob.